# will I be charged if I evaluate value using resource.data in firestore security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

from the video about firestore pricing here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NegFl9p_sE
it is said that if I use get() or exist() in security rules, I will be charged for one read.

how about evaluating a field of existing document using `resource.data` ? for example if I evaluating 4 fields from one documents like this:

```
    function isValidUserUpdate() {
            // to restrict, certain user fields can't be updated
        return incomingData().banned == existingData().banned
            && incomingData().uid == existingData().uid
            && incomingData().premiumUser == existingData().premiumUser
            && incomingData().verified == existingData().verified

    }

    function existingData() {
        // Data that exists on the Firestore document
      return resource.data;
    }

    function incomingData() {
        // Data that is sent to a Firestore document
      return request.resource.data;
    }
```

will get charged for 4 reads or just one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only charged get `get()` and `exists()`, just as the documentation says.  You are not charged for `request.resource.data`.